# How to save richtextbox text to a mysql DB with it being formatted(bold, italic...) and retrieve this text within code

Tags: mysql, wpf, vb.net, richtextbox

I am trying to save text from a richtextbox within a vb.net wpf application to a MySQL database with the formatting the same (bold, italic...).

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33563778/oracle-blob-datatype-to-richtextbox/33595287#33595287

Comment: The key is to use the RTF property, not the TEXT property. You can save this to any character field. NOTE: Also save the unformatted text for things like searching or reports that don't handle RTF. You'll regret it later if you don't.

Comment: yeah this worked perfect cheers, how do i go about verifying your answer, new to this :) @Steve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is to use the RTF property, not the TEXT property. You can save this to any character field.

NOTE: Also save the unformatted text for things like searching or reports that don't handle RTF. You'll regret it later if you don't.